# setState not working inside onChange function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to found out why this works

```
const Navigation:React.FC = () =>{
    const [Volume, setVolume] = useState<number>(50)
    const onChange = (event) => {
        setVolume(event.target.value);
    }
    return(
        <>
            <Slider label="Slider label" value={Volume} onChange={(event) => onChange(event)} max='100' min='0'/>
        </>
    )

}

export default Navigation
```

But this does not work

```
const Navigation:React.FC = () =>{
    const [Volume, setVolume] = useState<number>(50)
    return(
        <>
            <Slider label="Slider label" value={Volume} onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>)  => setVolume(event.target.value)} max='100' min='0'/>
        </>
    )

}

export default Navigation
```

It is giving this error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & HTMLElement'`

I would like to use the second one because it makes my code a lot shorter and cleaner.

any idea why or how I could make the second one work

Thank for the help

Comment: What does your `Slider` component look like?

Comment: An input range slider lets the user specify a numeric value which must be between two specified values.(I am using it to allow a user the change volume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm correct in assuming that this is a `Typescript` error, then you need the provide proper `type` for the event, there is no `value` property in the HTMLElement type, you need to use HTMLInputElement for the slider.

```
    const onChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setVolume(parseInt(event.target.value));
    }
```

Comment: when looking at the onChange type from the slider it is , (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLElement>) but the error stays the same if i add it. I changed the question code to reflect it

Comment: there is no `value` property in the `HTMLElement` type, you need to use `HTMLInputElement` for the slider.

Comment: yes that works, if I aslo parsInt the event.target.value, thanks a lot

Comment: yes, you need to `cast` the value to a number, so the typescript doesn't complain.